# ffmpeg add album cover art to mp3 with python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, jpeg, mp3

I've been trying to make a python script which merges a mp3 file with a .jpg, but I only get it to create a video out of both inputs, instead of a mp3 with the .jpg just as the cover. I have tried to look for ways other people have done that but I only seem to find the command-line way and nothing regarding python

```
    import ffmpeg

    input_image = ffmpeg.input(r'C:\Downloads\thumbnail.jpg')
    input_audio = ffmpeg.input(r'C:\Downloads\audio.mp4')

    (
        ffmpeg
        .concat(input_image, input_audio, v=1, a=1)
        .output(r'C:\Downloads\audio1.mp4').run()
    )
```

Thats the ffmpeg part i got in my script which works but not as I need it to

Comment: Could you specify what "as a cover" means? Where should the jpg be displayed?

Comment: @valid put it into the meta data of the file, like mp3s usually got some cover/picture on them

Comment: If I read this right, the [python module](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) is "just" a wrapper, ultimately creating `ffmpeg` shell commands. Plus, the wrapper seems incomplete. As you know how to create your solution via CLI you should just compile and run the shell commands yourself.

Comment: @valid yeah resolved to having the script execute the command via CLI and it works now, thank you!